# How to stream sqlite from memory?

Tags: java, sqlite, stream, in-memory, sqljet

I have data in a postgres database, I'm currently creating a sqlite db on disk, and then streaming it for clients. I'd prefer to skip the write to file step, and just stream from memory. I haven't seen any Java sqlite options that allows this.

Apparently a virtual file system (in memory) doesn't help with this either  AFAICT.

Comment: So in cleartext, you are trying to run sqlite as an in-memory database?

Comment: Yes. write new db in-memory, and then dump the contents as stream. I'm thinking of using sqljet and getting at the internals for the stream, very unclear.

Comment: this is the closest thing I've found: https://code.google.com/p/sqljet/issues/detail?id=125. However, there is no api to create a stream.

Answer (score 1):

> SQLite supports on-memory database management, which does not create any database files.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

see https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#how-to-use-memory-databases

Streaming or passing to other computers is not database feature, just use any binary or text-based protocols like JSON over TCP/IP.